# Add most of a id on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can to add a new id in my $(), in this code I added an only id, but I need add other more.
Thanks!

```
$('#editable-detail').editableTableWidget();

$('#editable-detail td.uneditable').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select many elements via multiple selectors using a comma:

```
$('#editable-detail1, #editable-detail2').editableTableWidget();
```

Or you could put a class, say `editable-table-widget`, on the ones you want to do this to, and select by class:

```
$('.editable-table-widget').editableTableWidget();
```

This leaves the rest of your code to deal with, since I imagine you'd want the same `change` event bound to the child elements. (**NOTE: you bound a change event to a `td` element...that's quite odd...**)

Your original code:

```
$('#editable-detail').editableTableWidget();
$('#editable-detail td.uneditable').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    return false;
});
```

Would be better written as one of the two following:

```
$('#editable-detail')
    .editableTableWidget()
    .find('td.uneditable')
        .on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
            return false;
        });
```

OR:

```
var editableDetail = $('#editable-detail').editableTableWidget();

editableDetail.find('td.uneditable').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    return false;
});
```

This change is beneficial because you aren't re-querying the DOM for the element with ID of `editable-detail`.

With that change in place, you could apply the lesson about using commas or a class with this change, and use the following for your whole code sample replacement:

```
$('.editable-table-widget')
    .editableTableWidget()
    .find('td.uneditable')
        .on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a comma-delimited list of selectors:

```
$('#editable-detail, #editable-detail2').editableTableWidget();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select multiple ID's using jQuery, just seperate them with a comma.

```
$('#editable-detail, #otherID').editableTableWidget();
  $('#editable-detail td.uneditable').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
  return false;
});
```

You can see it in action here: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/61s6fppL/)

Comment: Thanks, if I make this, the first id do not works, so only works the second id :(

Comment: Sounds like there may be some other issue going on then, because there shouldn't be anything wrong with the selector.

Comment: In the second var, is necessary add the second id?

Comment: @user3680708, I added a JSFiddle. As long as the syntax is the same, you should not be getting any selector issues.

Answer (score 1):

you either do like:

```
$('#editable-detail, #editable-detail2, #editable-detail3').editableTableWidget();
```

or (**Recommended**):

use classes instead of id (you should give them all the same class):

```
$('.editable-detail').editableTableWidget();
```

Comment: Thanks, the 1th option its ok, but no works good in my code.. so the second option is the most functional for my :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add comma to seperate them

```
$('#editable-detail, #otherid').editableTableWidget();
```